# Dynamics CRM 2016 not tracking email replies

Tags: dynamics-crm, outlook-addin, dynamics-crm-2016, server-side-sync

When a case is created, and emails are sent to the client, the mail syncs correctly between exchange/outlook, and CRM. However when a reply comes back from the client to the service representative, the mails are not automatically tracked as part of the original case that was set even though CRM reference details are present in the email subject line.  The track number is correctly injected into the subject of the email and is still present when the client responds.

Our setup is as follow:

CRM                      :               CRM 2016 on dedicated server (all roles)

Exchange             :               Exchange 2016 on dedicated server (all roles)

SQL                        :               SQL Server 2014 ENT. With DB failover on dedicated server (all roles)

Exchange is configured as Internal Relay, and has outlook anywhere and active sync configured and externally facing. (no other protocols)

CRM mail is configured with Email Profile Authentication using an impersonation account to access and communicate with exchange.

Email accounts are processed using server side synchronisation. And users are using CRM for outlook.

Emails automatically appear in CRM, and can be tracked and set regarding. Appointments and tasks also sync as expected.

The following screen grabs summaries the settings

[image: CRM email configuration]

[image: CRM Outlook configuration]

[image: Outlook configuration]

[image: CRM diagnostics]

Comment: Are you using 2016 outlook client or a previous version of outlook client?Tracking seems to be an issue when 2015 outlook client is used in conjunction with CRM 2016.

Comment: I am using 2016 outlook client

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that needs to be done here:

Under your Settings > Email, please make sure you add a bit more of digits to the incremental message counter, perhaps to 7. 
Tick the box that says "Track emails sent between Dynamics 365 users"

***NOTE***
For the Emails to create activities in CRM there are a couple of things you need to make sure happens:
- The Customer should reply to a CRM Active Queue
AND
- The tracking subject "CRM:000001" needs to match